# How to deal with large number of edges from few vertex in graph db

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

I'm trying to model a graph db based on large RDBMS data. Reason behind graph db is to answer a lot of relationship based questions, enable traversal between different nodes and performance. While modeling this, I'm noticing that few nodes have large set of outgoing edges.

For example, think about "category" as a vertex, "product" as another vertex. There are other vertices like "product" exist. However, a lot of edges originate from "category" out to other edges.Outgoing number of edges are in few 100,000.

Is this an alert?
are there better any design principles to proactively design this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your current data model looks something like this:

```
(:Category {name: 'Toy'})<-[:IS_A]-(:Product {id: 123})
```

and that some nodes with the `Category` [label](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-label) have an enormous number of related `Product`s.

To reduce the number of relationships and simplify your queries a bit, you can consider eliminating the `Category` nodes and instead adding an additional [label](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-label) to each `Product` node. For example:

```
(:Product:Toy {id: 123})
```

With this new data model, you could directly find all `Toy` products without traversing any relationships (e.g., `MATCH (t:Toy) RETURN t`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using "category" as a property of "product", which would both solve the super vertex problem and save resources. For example, if you want to find all products under a specific category, make an index for the "category" property.

In general, super vertices should be avoided in graph modeling because they have significant impact on query performance. If those edges are queried, most graph databases would cut off or do sampling. If it's inevitable, be sure to at least set limits when traversing through the out-going edges of these vertices.